# Find stationary points of the function $f(x,y) = (y^2-x^4)(x^2+y^2-20)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have problem in finding some of the stationary points of the function above. I proceeded in this way: the gradient of the function is:

$$ \nabla f = \left( xy^2-3x^5-2x^3y^2+40x^3 ; x^2y+2y^3-x^4y-20y \right) $$

So in order to find the stationary points, I must resolve the system:

$$ \begin{cases} 
xy^2-3x^5-2x^3y^2+40x^3 = 0 \\
x^2y+2y^3-x^4y-20y = 0
\end{cases} $$

So far I've found the points:

$$ (0,0) \qquad \left(\pm 2 \sqrt{10 \over 3} , 0 \right) \qquad (0, \pm \sqrt{10}) $$

But, I'm still blocked  when I've to found the points deriving by the system:

$$
\begin{cases} 
2x^6 + 3x^4 +x^2 -20 = 0 \\
y^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( x^4 - x^2 + 20 \right) \end{cases}
$$

Which I don't know how to solve. Can someone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you implied, you can factor the original system as $x(3x^4-40x^2+2x^2y^2-y^2)$ and $y(x^4-x^2-2y^2+20)=0$.

Taking $y=0$ gives you $x=0,x=\pm2\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}$. Taking $x=0$ gives you $y=\pm\sqrt{10}$.

So you are left to solve $3x^4-40x^2+2x^2y^2-y^2=0,x^4-x^2-2y^2+20=0$ and $x,y\ne0$. Substituting from the second into the first gives $2x^6+3x^4-39x^2-20=0$ (you dropped the $-40x^2$ here), which factorises as: $$(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+5)(2x^2+1)$$

Can I leave you to finish?

Answer (score 1):

WA gets
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
\grad((x^2+y^2-20) (y^2-x^4)) = (-6 x^5-4 x^3 (y^2-20)+2 x y^2, 2 y (-x^4+x^2+2 y^2-20))
$$
([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gradient%20%20(y%5E2%20-%20x%5E4)(x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20-%2020))) and nine real critical points ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20-6%20x%5E5-4%20x%5E3%20(y%5E2-20)%2B2%20x%20y%5E2%20%3D%200%20and%202%20y%20(-x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B2%20y%5E2-20)%20%3D%200%20for%20x,y)).

[image: WA solution]